# NuGet Json.Net Install Erros VS 2010 Shell

Tags: json.net, nuget

I am trying to install NuGet do that I can use Json.Net Extensions.

I have installed version 2.8.60318.667 (which was the download from Microsoft for VS2010.

When I try and install Json.Net by the Package Manager Console it fails

```
    PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.CSharp (≥ 4.3.0)'.
Install-Package : 'Microsoft.CSharp' already has a dependency defined for 'System.Dynamic.Runtime'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Newtonsoft.Json
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

PM>
```

When I try and do it via the Manage NuGet Packages UI Get this error.
[image: Json.Net Install Error]
when I then try to install Microsoft CSharp extension I get this error
[image: Microshoft CSharp Error]

When I click the Upgrade NuGet button at the bottom there is no update to 2.12 and the only thing I can find is for VS 2013

Is there a way to get this extension to work for VS2010 Shell?

Comment: Oh man 2010 is light years behind

Comment: I know but unfortunately I am constrained to it

Comment: go file an issue here https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues